# Relation between limit in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

I have only been just exposed to metric spaces and I am currently learning about limits of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have a question regarding the limits of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and how it relates to limits in $\mathbb{R}$.

Formally, say I have the metric space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard Euclidean metric. Now consider a sequence $\{x_j\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ where $x_j$ can be written in component form as $(x_{j,1}, \cdots x_{j,n})$ and assume that $\{x_j\}$ converges to $x$, i.e., $x_j \rightarrow x$ where $x$ can also be expressed in component form as $x = (x_1, \cdots x_n)$.

My question is, is it true that $x_j \rightarrow x$ if and only if $x_{j,m} \rightarrow x_m$ (where this convergence is in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ again with standard metric) for all $m = 1, 2, \cdots, n$? If true, how can I prove it?

Comment: Yes, it's true.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

Hints:

- Suppose that $x_j\rightarrow x$.  Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $M$ so that if $m>M$, then $\sqrt{\sum (x_{j,m}-x_m)^2}<\varepsilon$.  But then, each $|x_{j,m}-x_m|<\varepsilon$ because every term in the sum is positive.
- Suppose that each $x_{j,m}\rightarrow x_m$.  Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $M$ so that if $m>M$, then $|x_{j,m}-x_m|<\varepsilon$.  Then $\sqrt{\sum (x_{j,m}-x_m)^2}<\sqrt{n}\varepsilon$.

Comment: _Technically_, the second hint should use $|x_{j,m}-x_m|<\frac\varepsilon{\sqrt n}$, since it's $\sqrt{\sum (x_{j,m}-x_m)^2}<\varepsilon$ we want.

Comment: @Arthur Of course, but I (intentionally) left that detail for the $OP$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks, I got it now using your hints :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll use upper indices to indicate positions in a sequence and lower indices to indicate coordinates.

As a hint, we can say the sequence $\{\vec x_i\}$ converges to $\vec L$ in $\mathbb R^n$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$ the exists an $M$ such that:

$$m>M\implies(x^m_1-L_1)^2+(x^m_2-L_2)^2+...(x^m_n-L_n)^2<\epsilon^2$$

If the sequence $\{x^m_i\}$ converges to $L_i$ in $\mathbb R$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $M$ such that:

$$m>M\implies(x^m_i-L_i)^2<\epsilon^2$$

Can you think of any ways to connect these two statements?